# error ACE EDITOR, cuando escribo en el código, pone el texto en otro espacio ?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola
estoy utilizando **Ace Editor** 
y cuando estoy escribiendo código html, el texto lo escribe tres(3) espacios hacia atrás

como lo soluciono ?

Comment: Es un problema con la fuente usada. San google: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183031/ace-editor-cursor-behaves-incorrectly

Comment: Mil gracias @track3r  me soluciono el problema.